# Understanding トイレの方が来たらいいのに in these song lyrics

Tags: song-lyrics, parsing, modality

I've been listening to [a song called 布団の中から出たくない](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4DxPeLNVuw) recently and tried to translate some of the lyrics, since my Japanese is still on a beginner or lower intermediate level. I stumbled over one particular sentence while translating:

> トイレの方が来たらいいのに

I found out that it says something like "I wish the toilet would come", but I'm not sure about some parts of that sentence. Could someone please divide the sentence up into its grammatical components? The ending of the sentence is what confuses me the most, I don't really get what *kitara ii no ni* is supposed to mean.

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23226/9831

Comment: Thank you for your editing snailplane! Seems that I should have better checked out other posts before posting my problems. That will definitely not happen again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [linked question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23226/9831) explains `のに`. 
As for the first part (`トイレの方が`), it is a part of the comparison pattern (`Xの方がいい`), showing a preferred alternative, e.g. see [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24426/). It makes the focus of the sentence shift toward `トイレ` and also adds a bit of contrast against the actual situation.

Taken together, the sentence could be translated as "I wish *the toilet* would come [here] (instead of me having to go there)." It is further underlined by the later line `布団の中にすべてあればいいのに` ("It would be so nice if *everything* were inside the futon").

**EDIT**
Actually, after some reflection, I think that instead of comparison, this `方` should be taken in the literal meaning of side/way/(conversation’s) party. And `いい` is also not a part of comparison pattern but is part of [〜たらいい conditional.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43917/%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E3%81%84%E3%81%84-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%84-hope-temporal-syntax-and-over-literal-readings), which also adds a nuance of hope/wish. 
 I.e. “I wish that *the toilet* (lit. “the toilet’s side”) would come (here)”. It does not change the final interpretation much though.

Comment: @CaptnBobvious see edit, I think it works better that way